# Swift CSVImporter can't read the CSV file

Tags: swift, csv-import

I am using the CSVImporter pod in order to parse a CSV file uploaded from the iCloud Drive, the intention for every row, that is parsed, is to be uploaded to my database.

When the  `importFile()` is executed it prints the path but then it prints `"The CSV file couldn't be read."`

Q1: What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import CSVImporter

class importBatchVC: UIViewController,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var path=""
    var docURL = URL(string: "")

    @IBAction func chooseDoc(_ sender: Any) {
        let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeContent),String(kUTTypePlainText)], in: .import)
        importMenu.delegate = self
        importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil
    }

    @IBAction func importFile(_ sender: Any) {
        if docURL==nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please select a spreadsheet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            do {
                self.path = String(describing:docURL)
                print(path)

                let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path)
                importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFail {
                        print("The CSV file couldn't be read.")
                    }.onProgress { importedDataLinesCount in
                        print("\(importedDataLinesCount) lines were already imported.")
                    }.onFinish { importedRecords in
                        print("Did finish import with \(importedRecords.count) records.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        print("The Url is : \(String(describing: url))")
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url.standardizedFileURL, to: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent))

            self.docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            print("now check this: \(docURL!)")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Note: This is repost question that was closed as "duplicate" and the code above is the implementation suggested.

My initial and preferred implementation was to get the link of the iCloud drive file via `documentPicker` and parse/upload it to database on the fly but i was getting the same error as i get now: "The CSV file couldn't be read."

The explanation that was provided by Leo Dabus was:
 `"UIDocumentPickerModeImport The URL refers to a copy of the selected document. This document is a temporary file. It remains available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, you must move this file to a permanent location inside your sandbox."`

Q2: Considering that i don't need to keep a permanent file-just need to keep it till its parsed and then it will be in my database, why do i need to import it to `documentDirectory`, is there any way i could parse it via the link i get from documentPicker?

Code for my initial implementation:

```
 import UIKit
 import MobileCoreServices
 import CSVImporter

class importBatchVC: UIViewController,UIDocumentPickerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
 var path=""
 var docURL = URL(string: "")

@IBAction func chooseDoc(_ sender: Any) {
    let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypeContent),String(kUTTypePlainText)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

  @IBAction func importFile(_ sender: Any) {
    if docURL==nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please select a spreadsheet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else{
        do {
            self.path = docURL!.path
            print(path)

            let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: path)
            importer.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFinish { importedRecords in
                for record in importedRecords {
                    // record is of type [String] and contains all data in a line
                    print(record)
                }
            }

    }
}
}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
   docURL = url as URL
    print("The Url is : \(String(describing: url))")
}


func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:

The problem I see when trying to parse the file at `docURL` is the following line:

```
self.path = String(describing:docURL)
```

This is not the correct way to convert a file URL into a path. The proper code is:

```
self.path = docURL.path
```

Q2:

When you use the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in `import` mode, the URL you are given in the delegate method is only valid until the end of the delegate method. This is why you must copy/move the selected file.

From the documentation:

> The URLs refer to a copy of the selected documents. These documents are temporary files. They remain available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, move these files to a permanent location inside your sandbox.

So yes, you must make a copy. But you can delete the file when you are done parsing it.

Comment: Q1: it works!! Q2: `They remain available only until your app terminates'-im fine with that, once it's parsed i don't need it anymore anyway! Also with my initial implementation if i put: let contents = try! String(contentsOf: icloudDriveURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) i could print all the rows from the file picked! So why can i read it but i cannot parse it with CSVImporter?? Please help me understand.

Comment: You just said *"Q1: it works!!"* so why at the end of your comment do you say you can't parse it?

Comment: With the "make a copy" implementation it works. The Q2: refers to trying to parse it via the documentPicker link without making a copy of the file localy, my reply to Q2 refers to that.

Comment: I can't answer that since you have not provided that code in your question.

Comment: I have edited my question adding the code for my initial and preffered implementation, and now after changing the docURL path as per your suggestion it works either by saving or by just using the documentPicker link. I guess my question should have been: Can i parse a file upon its selection(once, then i dont need it anymore) from icloud drive via its documentPicker link? , apparently it seems i can... Shame my original question was marked as a duplicate

Comment: OK, so this question has been answered and solved using the first part of my answer, correct? Your only issue was converting the URL into a path.